# Closing an HTML <p> tag without the added line break

Tags: java, html, unit-testing, thymeleaf, jsoup

I'm working on a java function that generates some html code for an email using a thymeleaf template. I then want to unit test the resulting html string using JSoup. The problem I'm running into is that JSoup is picky about closing tags. While the browser can handle `<p>` blocks without a closing tag, JSoup requires the `</p>` to correctly extract the element text.

So the obvious solution then would be to just make sure to close the `<p>` tag right? The problem is, closing the `<p>` is adding an extra line break. I want to display:

> **Foo**
>                                                 **Bar**

but if I close the paragraph I get the following instead:

> **Foo
> 2**
>                                                 **Bar
> 2**

Below is an example of my test function. The first test will pass but the html will have the unwanted extra line break. The second function will display correctly but the test will fail. I'm at a bit off a loss for how to handle this. How do I structure my html to produce the desired output while allowing JSoup to correctly parse when testing?

```java
@Test
public void testJsoupParsePClosed() {
    // Test JSoup parsing with an explicitly closed paragraph tag
    Document testDoc = Jsoup.parse(
        "<html> <p id=\"272_6e8c478e-aabe-4789-ab22-8092e19c2dde\" ><strong>A test  academic message</strong></p>\n" +
            "<span id=\"272_6e8c478e-aabe-4789-ab22-8092e19c2dde\"><strong>From: X Yz <a href=\"mailto:xyz123@bucknell.edu?subject=Re:%20A%20test%20academic%20message\">&lt;xyz123@bucknell.edu&gt;</a></strong></span><br />\n" +
            "<div>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<span>This is a test of an academic message</span>\n" +
            "</div> </html>");

    String sp1 = testDoc.selectFirst("p#272_6e8c478e-aabe-4789-ab22-8092e19c2dde").wholeText();
    System.out.println("sp1 text: " + sp1);
    assertThat(sp1).isEqualTo("A test  academic message");
}
```

```java
@Test
public void testJsoupParsePOpen() {
    // test JSoup parsing with an unclosed paragraph tag
    Document testDoc2 = Jsoup.parse(
        "<html> <p id=\"272_6e8c478e-aabe-4789-ab22-8092e19c2dde\" ><strong>A test  academic message</strong><br />\n" +
            "<span id=\"272_6e8c478e-aabe-4789-ab22-8092e19c2dde\"><strong>From: X Yz <a href=\"mailto:xyz123@bucknell.edu?subject=Re:%20A%20test%20academic%20message\">&lt;xyz123@bucknell.edu&gt;</a></strong></span><br />\n" +
            "<div>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<span>This is a test of an academic message</span>\n" +
            "</div> </html>");

    String sp2 = testDoc2.selectFirst("p#272_6e8c478e-aabe-4789-ab22-8092e19c2dde").wholeText();
    System.out.println("sp2 text: " + sp2);
    assertThat(sp2).isEqualTo("A test  academic message");
}
```

Comment: Unless your `white-space` is set to `pre`, don't use "\n" in your HTML. If you want a line-feed, use `<br/>`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl The actual html I'm outputting does not have the newline tags. This was just a quick and dirty example.